# Java Error : Exception in Application start method

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error in the code posted below

I am trying to get a button to display text when clicked. I'm not sure what is causing the error

This is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.text.*;

public class javafx extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    Button button;
    Text text;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("My first window");
        button = new Button();
        button.setText("Click meh bro!");
        button.setTranslateX(0);
        button.setTranslateY(-100);
        button.setOnAction(this);

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(text , button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent shitgoindown) {
        if (shitgoindown.getSource() == button) {
                          //Creating a Text object 
           text = new Text();      
           text.setFont(new Font(31));
           text.setText("Hey bro , danks for clicken meh!");
         }
      }
    }
```

This is the error:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java javafx
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Children: child node is null: parent = StackPane@5f2d5162
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:435)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:103)
    at javafx.start(javafx.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application javafx

 ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is move `text = new Text();` outside of the event handler. The second thing you need to do is attach the event handler to the button.

The reason for your error is because you added the text to the StackPane but you never create the Text object until the button is pressed. So the solution is creating the Text object right away so it can be added to the StackPane. Then updating the Text object's text when the button is pressed.

> Example 1:

```
Button button;
Text text;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    text = new Text(); 
    text.setFont(new Font(31));

    primaryStage.setTitle("My first window");
    button = new Button();
    button.setText("Click meh bro!");
    button.setTranslateX(0);
    button.setTranslateY(-100);
    button.setOnAction(this::handle);

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(text , button);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    // Button was clicked, do something...
    text.setText("Hey bro , danks for clicken meh!");
}
```

> Example 2:

```
Button button;
Text text;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    text = new Text(); 
    text.setFont(new Font(31));

    primaryStage.setTitle("My first window");
    button = new Button();
    button.setText("Click meh bro!");
    button.setTranslateX(0);
    button.setTranslateY(-100);
    button.setOnAction((shitgoindown)->{               

       text.setText("Hey bro , danks for clicken meh!");
    });

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(text , button);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```